# Sequelize COUNT total gender as well as only male inside attributes

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am really new to `Sequelize` and for this project I am trying to count total number of gender as well as just male gender who came to our facility. We have defined gender as **1 for male** and 2 for female and 3 for others in our `MySQL` database. I am trying to use one endpoint to count total players by `gender_id` and count total male by `male` gender. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong on `selectedGender` part as I keep on getting same value as of `totalGender`?

```
{
  model: models.PlayersArrived,
  required: true,
  include: [
     {
       model: models.NotSpectators,
       required: true,
       where: {
         kl: null,
       },
       attributes:[
         [Sequelize.fn('COUNT',Sequelize.col("gender_id")), "totalGender"],
         [Sequelize.fn('COUNT',Sequelize.literal('gender_id',1)), "selectedGender"],
       ],
    },
  ],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this will work:

```
[Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.literal('CASE WHEN gender = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END')), 'males']
```